# Replace some of the text in select box option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have this Show/Hide select box **([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hk4wg/11/))** that gets a classname from a selected option and hides a corresponding unordered list item. I am at a loss to use `replace()` to replace the text `Hide` with `Show` or vice versa when an option is clicked.(e.g Show Month should become Hide Month on click.)

I also want to change all the options back to `Hide` when I click the Show All option.

When I used 
`findoption.replace('Hide','Show');` I got this `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error. Can anyone show me how to do that? Any help would be appreciated.

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showhidelist").change(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var findoption = $this.find('option:selected');
        var selected = findoption.data('hide');
        var show_hide_li = $("."+selected);
        if (show_hide_li.css("display") == "none") {
            show_hide_li.show(); 
           /* Want to Replace the text Hide with Show */
        }
        else if (show_hide_li.is(':visible')){
            show_hide_li.hide();
          /* Want to Replace the text Show with Hide */
        }
        else if (selected == "Reset") {
            $('li').show();
         /* Want to Replace the text Show with Hide if it's true */
        }
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<select class="showhidelist">
    <option data-hide="Reset">Show All</option>
    <option data-hide="year">Hide Year</option>
    <option data-hide="month">Hide Month</option>
    <option data-hide="day">Hide Day</option>
</select>

<ul id="list">
    <li class="year">2004</li>
    <li class="month">Feb</li>
    <li class="day">17</li>

<ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findoption is returns a jquery array, so you would need to access the first element there. I think the following will achieve what you're looking for (as far as the selected element goes).

```
findoption[0].innerHTML = findoption[0].innerHTML.replace('Show','Hide');
```

I'm not sure what you're really doing - this gets a little quirky, since you have the show/hide all and you'll have to go through the whole list to update them when you do. Also - you aren't getting a selected event when you re-select what's already selected.

UPDATE: this includes how to update all items in the list using `each()`

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hk4wg/15/

Comment: Yes, it's a little tricky. What I'm looking for is that for those hidden list items, when I click open the dropdown menu, I want their corresponding options to become `Show XXX`, and when they are visable, I want them to become `Hide XXX`.

Comment: Yeah - check out my jsfiddle - it should get you headed in the right direction. I didn't do the logic for the show all choice.

Comment: Actually my show/hides were backwards, I updated the fiddle link (13).  Freak_Droid mentions using the text() function - which I didn't know about, but that works too.

Comment: I think I'm targeting the wrong selector because I should target all the options in the select box, not just the selected one. Perhaps I need to make one more statement to trigger the text change in all options when the list item css is visible or hidden. I need to think about it more.

Comment: your fiddle is actually very close. The fact that I can't re-select the selected makes it seem a bit quirky~~

Comment: Yeah, I really don't think a dropdown is what you want. I showed how you can use the `each()` function to update all the elements in the list. The behavior gets confusing with what to do when show all is clicked and then one of the elemnents is hidden. Do you want a show all option then? or a hide all option? Or do you always want ONLY the show all option?

Comment: You may want something along the lines of the multiple selects on this page. http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/. 

I've never used this control, so i'm not recommending it per se, but that's the interface that I could see working for your problem.

Comment: Yes, Show All and Hide All are the problem. I think I'm going to avoid the confusion and change the first option text to something else. Thanks a lot for your help, caspian and Freak_Droid

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting the `text()` into the replace, and you could use the function that [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) has to replace the text.

```
findoption.text(function(_,text){ return text.replace('Hide', 'Show')});
```

Change the word 'Hide' or 'Show' depend on what you want.

**Update:**

I read in caspian comment, that you problem now is that you could not re-click an option clicked, try restarting the select to first option like:

```
$(".showhidelist").prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

Comment: I think I'm targeting the wrong selector because I should target all the options in the select box, not just the selected one. Perhaps I need to make one more statement to trigger the text change in all options when the list item css is visible or hidden.

Comment: thank you very much. It does most of the tricks. It disables the reset function of the first option `Show All` but I think I need to make a compromise here and create a button for the reset function.